# How do I get the option to return to a ID after alert “cancel”?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I get the option to return to the targeted value ID after loading the page and the alert “cancel”? But also to the former current value after a value is chosen?

Right now it selects the "current value" if I chose a value before I chose to "cancel" the alert.

But if I load a fresh page it will not go to the selected "current value" or to a targeted value ID either. It will go to a "disabled" option of no use. How do I fix this?

How do I make it to go to a targeted value ID (id="ger") option of my choice if I chose to "cancel" the alert directly after loading the page?

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#optFu').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();

            if (selected == 'auto') {
            if (!confirm('The ´´Automatic system´´ is limited. \n Are you sure you want to use this?')) {
                $(this).val($.data(this, 'current'));
                return false;
                } 
            }
        $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="LangFu" id="optFu">
<option value="" disabled>Common Languages:</option>
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option selected value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de" id="ger">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto" data-confirm=" The ´´Automatic Language Detection´´ does not detect laguadges in frames / sandbox. Are you sure you want to select this option? ">Auto Detect</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
$(function() {
  $('#optFu').val("de");
  $('#optFu').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected == 'auto') {
      if (!confirm('The ´´Automatic system´´ is limited. \n Are you sure you want to use this?')) {
        $(this).val("de");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="LangFu" id="optFu">
  <option value="" disabled>Common Languages:</option>
  <option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
  <option selected value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
  <option value="es">Spanish</option>
  <option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
  <option value="auto" data-confirm=" The ´´Automatic Language Detection´´ does not detect laguadges in frames / sandbox. Are you sure you want to select this option? ">Auto Detect</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your works the same as mine. If the page is freshly loaded it still chooses a disabled option if canceled. It only works correctly if I first chose a option and then chose to Auto and cancel. then it works.
In other words it works exactly like mine. No difference and the problem of a new loaded page is still there.

Comment: After a long fiddling I found the answer myself. The solution was simple, I need to add an automatic system to chose ``id="ger"`` when a amty value was chosen by my or your solution. The code I needed to add was this ``$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#opt").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#ger").prop('selected', true);
            }
            else {
                $("#ger").prop('selected', false);
            }
        })
    });``

Comment: Look at the answer I gave to myself after fiddling a lot with it, trying to find a solution. That extra code fixes this problem both with my and with your solution that has the same problem. But since I can not give myself a "answer V" to myself, I gave it to you, so that the question is closed with an answer since your codes work, it is just only 50% working exactly like my fist code with the question.

Comment: sorry if i don't really understand your question before, i updated my answer to meet your requirement.

Comment: Look test my solution and you will see your code does not do the exact same thing as mine. This new code of yours is still 50% correct but on the other way around. Because it needs to work as it does now, if the page is new loaded. But if you chose another option in the box before you chose the Auto option, then it should work like the old code did. Now you understand how it should work? Test my code solution and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

**After a long fiddling I found the answer myself.** But I will leave it online for others who may have the same problem to see the solution with the answer.

What I needed to do is add:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#opt").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#ger").prop('selected', true);
            }
            else {
                $("#ger").prop('selected', false);
            }
        })
    });
```

And by doing so tell the system that if a empty value is chosen then automatically the id="ger" would be chosen. That way I fixed the problem.

**This is how the entire code looks**

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#optFu').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();

            if (selected == 'auto') {
            if (!confirm('The ´´Automatic system´´ is limited. \n Are you sure you want to use this?')) {
                $(this).val($.data(this, 'current'));
                return false;
                } 
            }
        $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#opt").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#ger").prop('selected', true);
            }
            else {
                $("#ger").prop('selected', false);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="LangFu" id="optFu">
<option value="" disabled>Common Languages:</option>
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option selected value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de" id="ger">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto" data-confirm=" The ´´Automatic Language Detection´´ does not detect laguadges in frames / sandbox. Are you sure you want to select this option? ">Auto Detect</option>
</select>
```